# JBPM Designer No Run Simulation Button

Tags: jboss, drools, simulation, designer, jbpm

I followed the steps of this post https://developer.jboss.org/thread/194827 Integration  to set up and run JBPM Designer. The only difference is that I am using jbpm-designer-2.3.0.Final-tomcat.war.

The problem that I faced is that I cannot see the run simulation button. I can see only the process paths button. What should I do to make the "run simulation" button visible?
[image]

Comment: 'simulation' feature is added in jBPM 6 release. This feature was not available in jBPM 5 release. You should use latest version of jBPM

Comment: I have upadete to the latest varsion of jpbm designer 2.4. Now I see the simulation button but after click it I get a pop up window saying "Unable to simulate". Any ideas?

Comment: The "Unable to simulate" solved by increasing the pergem memory